# how to invoke visual studio commands from c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Can i execute Visual Studio commands like 'File.AddExistingProject' from C# code?
if so how?

other sample commands..

> Debug.Print varA
>   File.CheckOutforEdit etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of DTE for the same, I have done something similar in past here is my code to do the same

```
DTE dte = null;

try
{
    dte = (DTE)Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.11.0");
}
catch
{    
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("devenv");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    try
    {
        dte = (DTE)Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.11.0");
    }
    catch
    {
        //cant do much nw, notify
    }
}

SearchResult result = (SearchResult)listFiles.SelectedItem;

dte.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenFile", result.FileName);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
dte.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GoTo", labelLineNo.Text);
dte.MainWindow.Activate();
dte.ActiveDocument.Activate();
```

I hope this helps you

so you may call

```
dte.ExecuteCommand("File.AddExistingProject", parameters as needed);
```

Comment: thanks for the ans..have one more question...is there a command to open "Add Connection" dialog box.??

Comment: I am not sure which connection you are referring to, you may try to figure out commands by typing `>` in immediate window followed by the expected command. Alternatively you can make use of Find/Command box to find the same. see more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1665hyw1(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Note: For Visual Studio 2013 (or any version other than 2012) you'll need to change the VisualStudio.DTE.11.0 accordingly.  2013 it would be "VisualStudio.DTE.12.0".

Comment: @Pushpraj Ruhal - Thread.Sleep(2000)?  I wish my Visual Studio loaded in 2 seconds!

Comment: @ppittle Actually this snippet is from one of my tool I made and 2000 ms was implemented as a safe side to make sure the VS is loaded and ready for receiving commands if not already running. BTW VS usually loads in approx a sec on my pc.